# How nuclear fission works in power plants?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atoms

As per the laws we are not able to see atoms (atom is microscopic). Then how does the nuclear fission works?

*. In nuclear fission, splitting atoms is a exact calculation or probability(like we 1 gram of uranium it will contain millions of atoms, some of them will split)?

also, please explain Nuclear fission process(what exactly happens in).

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission then ask any questions here

Comment: If your question would be closed, I suggest a next try on engineers.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Have a look here http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/nuclear-fission-basics.html

Comment: Clarify your questions. You are currently asking two questions: 1) "Then how does the nuclear fission works?"; 2) "In nuclear fission, splitting atoms is a exact calculation or probability?". I'm not sure the second question is even a question...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, although it's not home-work, it shows no effort (there is plenty of material in Internet).

Comment: I do not understand what us "not seeing atoms" has to do with the workings of nuclear fission.

Answer (score 1):

> In nuclear fission, splitting atoms is a exact calculation or probability(like we 1 gram of uranium it will contain millions of atoms, some of them will split)?

In nuclear decays , when a nucleus splits into fragments, yes, there is a probability distribution characterized by the [lifetime of the state](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/halfli2.html). Eventually an unstable mass will decay into its component parts.

Now in the case of fission to be used  in a reactor, there exist processes that can enhance the probability of decay/fragmentation. Example  U235:

[image: fission u235]

> The fission of U-235 in reactors is triggered by the absorption of a low energy neutron, often termed a "slow neutron" or a "thermal neutron"

Energy is released in the split.

If one engineers that the neutrons coming from the first split (N in the image) are slow enough to be capture by another U235 nucleus , given enough mass , [called critical mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nucene/moder.html) the process can be slow  and self sustaining in reactors, releasing energy for usage:making steam.

If a critical mass is brought together then one has an atomic  bomb.

Answer (score 0):

Nuclear fission uses a chain reaction. With a large enough mass, as one atom decays it will set off other atoms to decay which will lead to the release of a large amount of heat. This heat boils water which turns a turbine to generate electricity.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's a few questions in there.   First, Atoms can (kind of) be seen by electron microscope, so it's not entirely accurate that they can't see Uranium.  But scientists had figured out there were atoms long before they actually saw one, through experimentation.    This is long, but the first few parts move pretty quick and it covers the discovery of the atom in pretty good detail.    http://www.nobeliefs.com/atom.htm

In the link, it mentions that James Rutherford discovered the Proton in 1920 and he was the first to calculate the mass of an atom through experimentation.   He was able to deduce that there was probobly a missing piece without charge, but with mass in the Atomic Nucleus, but that missing piece (the Neutron) wasn't discovered till 1932.

Other discoveries were made, Henri Becquerel discovered that Uranium gave off X-rays (1895 or 96).  Some years later Marie Curie discovered Radium, which is many times more radioactive than Uranium and scientists realized that a lot of energy was coming from those elements.    In combination with Einstein's E=MC^2 scientists began to understand that elements like Uranium contained an enormous amount of energy.

So they had the basic working model for the atom by 1932 once the Neutron had been discovered and it's mass measured, and this was a good working model.  They now knew not just how many protons were in an element but how many neutrons in isotopes.

So, that's where it began.   Not long after that, they figured out that U235 was much more fissionable than U238, and U235 was the primary fuel used in Nuclear Plants (and bombs) for the next few decades.   99.3% of the Uranium that is mined is U238, so U235 is much harder to get.  The separation process was an enormous study in and of itself, but once they had U235 in high concentrations it can be made made fissionable a few ways.    A sustainable reaction basically involves hitting it with Neutrons, and as the U235 splits, it releases more Neutrons which hit more U235.   It's a fairly simple model on paper, but a more complicated in practice cause as this happens, the Uranium wants to fly apart like a powerful bomb.  It doesn't want to stay in one place and maintain a chain reaction.

Not sure that helps, but I find it's sometimes helpful to go back to the beginning.

As to your exact calculation question, since the fuel itself isn't an exact percentage of U235, there's never going to be an exact measurement, though obviously, the goal is to shoot for most of the U235 to be "spent".

The reaction can take place a few different ways.  (see picture below).    High concentration of U235 is enriched Uranium.   U238 is non-enriched and considered safer.

http://physics.nayland.school.nz/VisualPhysics/NZ-physics%20HTML/17_NuclearEnergy/Pix/Equations_UraniumFission.png

The gist of the process is Neutron bombardment of U235.   In more modern plants, a lot of the Neutrons come from heavy water, so if the water uncovers the core, the reaction stops - and so, no "china syndrome".    That's what went wrong in Chernobyl.   Chernobyl wasn't a heavy water plant so the fuel was hotter and water was used to keep the process from going kaboom.   In what was basically a really stupid experiment, the plant operators in Chernobyl were instructed to uncover the core which lead to the Core getting crazy super-heated and it blew up like a bomb, blowing the cover off the plant.   Different plants undergo the fission process in different ways so there's no one specific answer.   Some plants run of Plutonium, like the plant in Japan.   The Plutonium was from Bombs and so, it seemed like a good idea at the time, but when the earthquake happened, the Plutonium was a bigger mess than Uranium would have been.  It wasn't as bad as Chernobyl, but it was pretty bad.

Newer Candu reactors use heavy water and non-enriched Uranium (99.3% U238).   Thorium reactors are being studied and Thorium would probobly be a cleaner fuel than Uranium with a less hot waste product, at least, based on what little I've read.    Here's a link on types of Nuclear Plants.

http://www.world-nuclear.org/info/Nuclear-Fuel-Cycle/Power-Reactors/Nuclear-Power-Reactors/

Hope that wasn't too long, but your question wasn't precisely clear and I thought the history was relevant too.